# Question about vector derivative

Tags: matrices, transpose

The gradient of a scalar-valued function is calculated. The $H$ matrix is symmetrical here and there is differentiate to both occurence of $x$ to $x$. My professor choose to write $y$ for the vector we differentiate to.

I found a transpose rule for differentiating here, yet I do not understand how it works in the solutions of the problem in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KMOI.png).

Why does $x\cdot(Hy)$ become $x^T H y$, instead of $xH$? 
Why and how do they continue swapping transposed vectors and matrices.

Any answer would be appreciated, a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $x^THy$ is a scalar, and a scalar is equal to its transpose. Hence,

$$
x^THy = (x^THy)^T = y^T H^T x.
$$

Also, if the dot-product between vectors $a$ and $b$ is denoted $a\cdot b$. Then we can also write

$$
y^T H^T x = y \cdot (H^T y).
$$

See [The properties of matrix transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Properties)

Comment: Very clear, thank you.

Comment: @mroWsymaS You're welcome :)